# where is call part in Controller for Route::currentRouteNameStartWith()

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, reactjs

I use Route::currentRouteNameStartWith('overview') in view.
but I don't find where is called in controller.
please help me.

In sidebar

```
<li class = "{{ Route::currentRouteNameStartWith('overview') ? 'mm-active': ''}}">
    <a href="{{ route('overview')}}">@lang('Overview')</a>
</li>
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you explain what you're looking for? By the way, only 1 tag is relevant to your question. It looks like you're using Laravel, so only `php` and `laravel` would be appropriate tags.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.